# Updated Visual Studio 2015 RTM from Update 1 to Update 2, now Cordova Project is "Incompatible"

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I updated my Visual Studio 2015 RTM from Update 1 to Update 2 and now my Cordova project won't open. I get the following error message instead of my project files:

> This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual
>   Studio.

I've installed the following hot fix and rebooted my machine and it made no difference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt695655.aspx

The only option I get for that project is to edit my `.jsproj` file. But I haven't a clue what I'd have to change to make it work.

Here's my version info for Visual Studio:

[image: Here's my version info for Visual Studio]

**How do I get my project to work with the new update to Visual Studio 2015?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what ever reason, Visual Studio seemed to remove the Tools for Apache Cordova and I had to reinstall them from scratch. Once I'd reapplied version 8.1 of the tools, the project loaded up just fine.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't see the VS Tools for Apache Cordova listed under my installed products in the About dialog.  From where/how did you install the tools?  Did you use the Extensions and Updates or did you manually install from a website?  Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have figured out what I needed.  I'm installing VS Tools for Apache Cordova Update 10 from the Project menu...will see if it fixes my problem.